# calculate angles between O'clock hands

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

suppose that  now  it is $1:50$, we need to calculate  angle between these  hands first  because we have  $12$ hour system per day and night and they are equal, each hour  corresponds  $360/12=30$, from  $10$ to $1$  we have $30+30+30=90$, but i want to know what should be  degree of angle  at the same time from $1$  to $2$?

Because there is $30$ degree and  $5$  dot, each one should equal to  $30/5=6$  right? or? please help me

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "from 1 to 2" and "5 dots"!

Comment: Tip: when using commas, a space should follow immediately afterwards, as with a period, question mark, exclamation point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extra angle is due to extra $50$ min. after $1:00$. For $60$ min. hour hand moves $30^\circ$, so for $50$ min. it moves by $\frac{50}{60}\cdot30^\circ=25^\circ$

So total angle b/w hr hand and min. hand at $1:50$ $=90^\circ+25^\circ=115^\circ$

Comment: why  50 minute?i could not understand it

Comment: because time is $1:50$. So at $1:50$, minute hand would be at $10$ and hour hand would be b/w $1$ and $2$ and how much angle it covers after $1$ depends on the minutes passed after it which is $50$ here.

Comment: Future reference: To denote, e.g., $115^\circ$, use `115^\circ`, and not `115^0` = $115^0$

Comment: @amWhy: I got it from the edit. Thanks for reminding anyways :)

Comment: general question,suppose  there is  1:40,so it means that from 1 to  2 in this case is 40/60*30=20?

Comment: Yes, as I was posting the comment, PyRulez was editing! ;-)

Comment: @dato: exactly.

Comment: then  what if  it shows 1:37  or 1:24? what is general formula

Comment: @dato: if it shows $1:\overline{ab}$, then extra angle would be $\dfrac{\overline{ab}}{60}\cdot30^\circ$

Comment: but non extra would not be 30 right?

Comment: for example 1:37.it shows  that small hand is  37 minute,what is angle from this to 1?

Comment: $37$ corresponds nearest to $8$, so angle from $8$ to $1$ is $(30+30+30+30+30)^\circ$. Now, for angle past $1$ would be $\dfrac{37}{60}\cdot30^\circ$ and the angle preceding $8$ from $37$ is $3\cdot 6=18^\circ$. so total angle $=(150+18+\dfrac{37}{60}\cdot30)^\circ$

Comment: so i would solve this problem like this.because each hour corresponds  $30$ and here is $5$ clock dots,between  35 and 40,it means that 37 corresponds  $18$,because each one corresponds  $30/5=6$  and  $40-37=3$ so totally   $3*6=18$ ,so $150+18$ right?  and plus $37/60*30=18.5$  is this correct?

Comment: now i understand everything

Comment: yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

As the Minute hand traverses, in $60$ minutes $360^\circ$

In $1$ Hour $50$ Minutes $=110$ minutes it will traverse $\frac{110}{60}\cdot 360^\circ=660^\circ\equiv300^\circ\pmod{360^\circ}$

As the Hour hand traverses, in $12$ hours $=720$ minutes $360^\circ$

In $1$ Hour $50$ Minutes $=110$ minutes it will traverse $\frac{110}{720}\cdot360^\circ=55^\circ$

So, angle at $1:50$ should be $(300-55)^\circ=245^\circ$ which is the reflex angle

So, the obtuse angle will be $|245-360|^\circ=115^\circ$

Comment: not big angle,small one

Comment: @dato, please find the edited answer