# difference between angles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

i could not understand exactly what is asked  in the following  question:

What is difference in the degree measures of the angles formed by  Hour hand and minute Hand of a clock  at $12:35$ and  $12:36$

i can't understand because,i have calculated angles  of each others,namely $12:35$ creates

$35/60*30=17.5$ degree,while  $12:36$ will  create $36/60*30=18$,so difference between  them is  $0.5$,but in GRE  book answer is $5.5$,please help me  to clarify what is my fault?

EDITED:

finally i understood what it is asked,it asked that what is a difference between angles created by Hour hand and  Minute Hand.
$1 Hour=30$  which means that  in 1 minute it advance by $30/60=0.5$,while  minute hand  by per minute is increased by $6$,s difference between them is $6-0.5=5.5$,i have then question what is difference between $12:35$ and   $12:38$? $6-1.5=4.5?

Comment: The minute hand moves as well

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440522/calculate-angles-between-oclock-hands

Comment: but i have calculated according my previous question

Comment: what is asked i can't understand

Comment: Well, lookit, in one minute, the minute hand advances six degrees, as you said, and the hour hand advances half a degree. But they’re moving in the same direction, so the minute hand gets ahead of the hour hand by only five and a half degrees.

Comment: but if time will be different?

Answer (score 0):

In 1 minute, hour hand advances by 0.5 degrees. In 3 minutes, it would advance by 1.5 degrees.
In 1 minute, minute hand advances by 6 degrees. In 3 minutes, it would advance by 18 degrees.

So, the difference after 3 minutes is 16.5 degrees.

Or, Difference in 1 minute is 5.5, in 3 minutes, it would be 16.5.

That is to say, difference in 60 minutes would be 5.5*60=330 degrees. It can be seen visually as well. At 12 o'clock, both hands coincide. At 1 o'clock, minute hand has traversed 360 degrees and hour hand has moved only 30 degrees. So, difference is of 330 degrees. Or, 30 degrees from other way.